# Geolocation with JS

Tags: javascript, geolocation

i have a little problem with my JS-script. 
I want to ascertain the location and currant timezone of the user on my page.
I tested it with Firefox, MS Internet Explorer and MS Edge. The problem is, it works sometimes and sometimes it don't works. And don't know why.

In Firefox i get the request, if i really allow this function soever. But i don't get the longitude and latidute.

If i try it by me iPhone it works all the time.

```
function getLocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        function showPosition(position) {;
            location_latitude = position.coords.latitude
            location_latitude = location_latitude.toFixed(6);
            location_longitude = position.coords.longitude
            location_longitude = location_longitude.toFixed(6)
            location_accuracy = position.coords.accuracy
            location_accuracy = location_accuracy.toFixed(2);

            var gmt = new Date();
            var location_gmt_difference = (gmt.getTimezoneOffset() / 60 / -1).toFixed(1);

            options_location_input.location_time_zone.value = location_gmt_difference
            options_location_input.location_latitude.value = location_latitude
            options_location_input.location_longitude.value = location_longitude
            options_location_input.location_accuracy.value = location_accuracy
        };
    };
```

Can someone help me. I dispairing!

Answer (score 0):

Are you always *serving* the page? It doesn't work if just viewing the page on the filesystem; the page must be served.

Comment: Hey, yes. I serving it with XAMPP on my computer.

Comment: The problem you may have if you are running on local is that your xampp does not know in which public ip address is running, so no geolocation can be obtained. Anyway, geolocation in client side must be (legally) allowed by the user, otherwise you can get the request ip address of the client in your server side code.

Comment: Add an error-handling function as the second parameter to `getCurrentPosition` to display why it not work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: @arkadianriver: Now i add the error-function. I receive this message: `ERROR(2): Unknown error acquiring position`